# How to use the for statement to create thousands of variables in python

Tags: python, for-loop, variable-assignment

If you want to create tens of thousands of variables in Python, is there a way to do this in a for statement.  What I want is a code that, when given a number and a value, can create that number of variables and assign them that value.

```
def createVars(num, somevalue):
    for x in range(num):
        var1 = somevalue
        var2 = somevalue
```

The idea is for the loop to continue making variables with reliable names(var3, var4, etc.) and assigning them to some given value.  How could you make this system that could create variables without explicitly having to name all of them?

Comment: use either `locals` or `globals`

Comment: Have we all forgotten that `mylist[0]` or `mylist.get('var_0')` is just as real a variable as `var_0`?

Comment: You do not need this. Use a list. That's what lists are for.

Comment: OP, in all likelihood, you don't actually want to do this. If you need thousands of variables, put them in a container and access them like var[1] instead of var1. The way you are trying to do it is paddling against the current.

Comment: Furthermore: even your accepted answer is using a container to access all your variables. It just happens to be the already existing python var table. Make things easier on yourself and go learn about the keyword 'list', and the list shorthand syntax, e.g. [1, 2, 3]

Comment: @electron1 Can you remove my answer from accepted? Also can you provide your reasons for asking this question? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use globals():

```
>>> for i in xrange(10):
...     globals()["x%d" % i] = i
... 
>>> x0
0
>>> x1
1
>>> x2
2
>>> x10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x10' is not defined
```

Comment: This is technically possible, but I'm 99.9% sure that a `list`, `dict`, or similar data structure is what the asker would've wanted if he or she knew about them. It's like a question asking how to draw shapes to the console when the desired shapes were just letters and the real question should've been "how do I print?".

Comment: Looking at the OP's score, they're probably a new coder (nothing wrong with that), so they probably just don't know about how to use data structures. Their question asks how to create lots of variables and assign them all the same value. A simple `[somevalue for n in range(num)]` would create all those variables, giving each a reliable name (e.g. `mylist[3]`) with the given value, without having to name them.

Comment: This does not even work. I am sick of people telling other people to do this when it doesn't even work. [Modifying `locals()` like that doesn't actually affect a function's local variables.](http://ideone.com/J3lWxe)

Comment: Things like that are why I've never tried to mess with `locals()` or `global()` - it's like sticking your hand into a motor.

Comment: `mylist[0]` is just as much a variable/attribute/etc. as `x0` - a reference to some value. Creating large quantities of named variables in this manner instead of learning about (remember, OP is most likely still learning) and using proper data structures is a terrible practice.

Comment: What test case does this allow you to address that can't be addressed using  a member of a container or data structure? Are there any concrete examples?

Comment: Well, using `globals()` is recommended over `locals()` because `locals()` does not work inside functions in CPython. According to the API documentation, updates to locals() is never guaranteed to actually update the local symbol table and it is recommended that you don't modify it. See here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals

Comment: This question is a classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It's clear what the OP's problem is, the OP's attempted solution is horrible, and you insist on trying to provide ways to make the OP's attempted solution work without any mention of the best ways to solve the underlying problem. You're making global variables now. That's not a tremendous improvement. Do you want to give the OP the impression that whenever he needs to store N things, he needs N *global* variables? What happens when he needs a recursive function?

Comment: It's still a massive discourtesy to tell someone to modify `globals()` instead of teaching them about data structures. You might as well modify `globals()` to create single variables as well, right? Use it for everything. And then you start trying to use classes and functions and all that good stuff, and suddenly your variables don't work like you expected them to and people recoil in horror when you show them the code and ask them how to fix it. This answer harms more than it helps, in my opinion.

Comment: To me, at least, it was blindingly obvious that the OP hadn't yet learned about data structures and didn't know that they were exactly what he or she needed.

Comment: I think the assumption that a new SO user has a real need for `globals()` is a much bigger one than the assumption that a new SO user isn't sure how to ask about data structures.

Comment: The question mentions nothing about creating an interpreter. All it asks is how to programmatically assign many variables. There was no need to jump straight to mucking around with `locals()` or `globals()`.

Comment: It's certainly possible that your case of [being a new SO user but also a veteran programmer is typical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect) and the OP really was searching for ways to mess with internals, but [I wouldn't bet on it](https://xkcd.com/1132/).

Comment: Yes, but I also enjoy learning from experience. When I think a user is very most likely new at programming, I will give them an answer geared towards new programmers. When in doubt, you can always comment on the question with something like "have you tried making a `list`, or is there a reason why that wouldn't work for your application?".

Comment: To clarify why I was actually asking, I was really trying to find a way to make many named variables that were not in a list.  I couldn't find anything about the subject elsewhere, so I decided to ask.  The only application I had in mind was multiple objects with their own methods to be called at once with one small statement, which I quickly discovered could not happen easily. I had no plans to put the information into practical use. I just wanted the information for future reference.

Comment: @electron1: The application you were thinking of is still better done with a list. `for thing in l: thing.method()`. You can even write it on one line if you really want. It would be much harder and more awkward to do that with 2000 named variables.

Answer (score 2):

```
def createVars(num, somevalue):
   l = [{'var'+str(x):somevalue} for x in xrange(num)]
   return l
```

Comment: Since the key is basically just a number anyway, this could probably just be `return [somevalue for n in xrange(num)]` (or `range` for Python 3).